# How can I execute a TensorFlow graph from a protobuf in C++?

Tags: protocol-buffers, tensorflow

I got a simple code form tutorial and output it to .pb file as below:

mnist_softmax_train.py

```
x = tf.placeholder("float", shape=[None, 784], name='input_x')
y_ = tf.placeholder("float", shape=[None, 10], name='input_y')

W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10]), name='W')
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]), name='b')
tf.initialize_all_variables().run()
y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x,W)+b, name='softmax')

cross_entropy = -tf.reduce_sum(y_*tf.log(y))

train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(cross_entropy, name='train_step')
train_step.run(feed_dict={x:input_x, y_:input_y})
```

---

In C++, I load the same graph, and feed in fake data for testing:

```
Tensor input_x(DT_FLOAT, TensorShape({10,784}));
Tensor input_y(DT_FLOAT, TensorShape({10,10}));   
Tensor W(DT_FLOAT, TensorShape({784,10}));   
Tensor b(DT_FLOAT, TensorShape({10,10}));
Tensor input_test_x(DT_FLOAT, TensorShape({1,784}));

for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<10;j++)
        input_x.matrix<float>()(i,i+j) = 1.0;    

    input_y.matrix<float>()(i,i) = 1.0;
    input_test_x.matrix<float>()(0,i) = 1.0;
}

std::vector<std::pair<string, tensorflow::Tensor>> inputs = {
  { "input_x", input_x },
  { "input_y", input_y },
  { "W", W },
  { "b", b },
  { "input_test_x", input_test_x },
};

std::vector<tensorflow::Tensor> outputs;
status = session->Run(inputs, {}, {"train_step"}, &outputs);

std::cout << outputs[0].DebugString() << "\n";
```

However, this fails with the error:

```
Invalid argument: Input 0 of node train_step/update_W/ApplyGradientDescent was passed float from _recv_W_0:0 incompatible with expected float_ref.
```

The graph runs correctly in Python. How can I run it correctly in C++?

Comment: What error do you get when you try to run this?

Comment: Sorry, I had modified my code. If I run the train_step graph, there will be a error message "Invalid argument: Input 0 of node train_step/update_W/ApplyGradientDescent was passed float from _recv_W_0:0 incompatible with expected float_ref."

Comment: [Loading a TensorFlow graph with the C++ API](https://medium.com/jim-fleming/loading-a-tensorflow-graph-with-the-c-api-4caaff88463f)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue here is that you are running the `"train_step"` target, which performs much more work than just inference. In particular, it attempts to update the variables `W` and `b` with the result of the gradient descent step. The error message

```
Invalid argument: Input 0 of node train_step/update_W/ApplyGradientDescent was passed float from _recv_W_0:0 incompatible with expected float_ref.
```

...means that one of the nodes you attempted to run (`"train_step/update_W/ApplyGradientDescent"`) expected a mutable input (with type `float_ref`) but it got an immutable input (with type `float`) because the value was fed in.

There are (at least) two possible solutions:

1. If you only want to see predictions for a given input and given weights, fetch `"softmax:0"` instead of `"train_step"` in the call to `Session::Run()`.
2. If you want to perform training in C++, do not feed `W` and `b`, but instead assign values to those variables, then continue to execute `"train_step"`. You may find it easier to create a [`tf.train.Saver`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#Saver) when you build the graph in Python, and then invoke the operations that it produces to save and restore values from a checkpoint.

Comment: Thanks so much! But what do you mean "do not feed W and b"? Can't I create a Tensor for W or b as input in C++ ?

Comment: The issue is that `W` and `b` are TensorFlow *variables*, which means that feeding them isn't supported. Instead, to set their value, you should run an Assign op that assigns a value to them. One way you could do this would be to add some ops to your graph (in Python) like `W.assign(tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name="w_placeholder"), name="w_assign")`, then you could call `Session::Run()` passing `"w_assign"` as the target, and `"w_placeholder:0"` as the tensor to be fed (and similarly for `b`).

Comment: Thanks again, by the way, what is the correct method to save training data in .pb file which I can use later in C++? I use tf.train.write_graph() but it  seems that the protobuf didn't hold training data.

Comment: We're still developing support for this at the moment, but [my answer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34343259/is-there-an-example-on-how-to-generate-protobuf-files-holding-trained-tensorflow/34343517#34343517) has a rough set of steps for generating a portable proto.

Comment: So, if I understood correctly - there is no way to train the graph from C++? I'm asking this because sometimes feeding data through Python is not practical (imagine custom storage for very large voice data, written on C++/C#). Or there is a way?

Comment: No, that's not correct. You *can* train the graph from C++. In that case you would certainly not feed the variables that you are trying to train. Instead, you'd add a `Session::Run()` call to run their initializers (i.e., in Python, the `tf.initialize_all_variables()` operation), and then run the `train_step` operation in a loop.