# How to serialize both the graph and values in a protobuf file?

Tags: tensorflow

The Android example that comes with Tensorflow downloads a protobuf file for InceptionV3 which contains both the graph and the values from the model. In the docs, I could only find how to serialize the graph (`tf.Graph.as_graph_def`) or save the variable values with a `tf.train.Saver`. How can you save everything to a single file, as done for that example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I answered a similar question on this topic: [Is there an example on how to generate protobuf files holding trained Tensorflow graphs?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34343517/3574081)

The basic idea is to use [`tf.import_graph_def()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/framework.html#import_graph_def) to replace the variables in the original (training) graph with constants, and then write out the resulting `GraphDef` using [`tf.Graph.as_graph_def()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/framework.html#Graph.as_graph_def).

Comment: Seems to be exactly what I am looking for. Thanks!