# tensorflow difference between saving model via exporter and tf.train.write_graph()?

Tags: python, tensorflow, protocol-buffers

What  is difference between saving a model by

1. using exporter as specified in tensorflow serving:

eg:

```
from tensorflow.contrib.session_bundle import exporter
#from tensorflow_serving.session_bundle import exporter
saver = tf.train.Saver(sharded=True)
model_exporter = exporter.Exporter(saver)
model_exporter.init(
        sess.graph.as_graph_def(),
        named_graph_signatures={
            'inputs': exporter.generic_signature({'images': x}),
            'outputs': exporter.generic_signature({'scores': y})})
model_exporter.export(export_path, tf.constant(FLAGS.export_version), sess)
```

2. Using tf.train.write_graph() and tf.train.Saver() directly:

eg:

```
with sess.graph.as_default():
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    saver.save(sess, path, meta_graph_suffix='meta', write_meta_graph=True)
```

Question is in continuation of [TensorFlow saving into/loading a graph from a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38947658/tensorflow-saving-into-loading-a-graph-from-a-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the Exporter is now officially deprecated, the new protocol for saving graph and data is to use Saver.  Here is an excellent blog with sample code:  https://blog.metaflow.fr/tensorflow-how-to-freeze-a-model-and-serve-it-with-a-python-api-d4f3596b3adc.

Answer (score 0):

Exporter is used after you train a model and want to serve it (use it for inference).

Saver is used for checkpointing when you train a model.

Comment: How is that different than using FreezeGraph to prepare a frozen graph for inferencing?  In other words, does one need to use Exporter, if one is using freeze_graph()?

Comment: And did this change with TF1.0+, as I see very little documentation on Exporter now.

Comment: For example, the latest warn message (TF1.1) says this:

`WARNING:tensorflow:From <ipython-input-34-eebd3eb6cfc5>:17: generic_signature (from tensorflow.contrib.session_bundle.exporter) is deprecated and will be removed after 2017-06-30.
Instructions for updating:
Please use SavedModel instead.`