# tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES on output_graph.pb resulting in empty list

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm trying to extract all the weights/biases from a saved model `output_graph.pb`.

I read the model:

```
def create_graph(modelFullPath):
    """Creates a graph from saved GraphDef file and returns a saver."""
    # Creates graph from saved graph_def.pb.
    with tf.gfile.FastGFile(modelFullPath, 'rb') as f:
        graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
        tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')

GRAPH_DIR = r'C:\tmp\output_graph.pb'
create_graph(GRAPH_DIR)
```

And attempted this hoping I would be able to extract all weights/biases
within each layer.

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    all_vars = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES)
    print (len(all_vars))
```

However, I'm getting a value of 0 as the len.

Final goal is to extract the weights and biases and save it to a text file/np.arrays.

Comment: I'm trying to re-use this, but I'm not getting create_graph to work as I am getting a `DecodeError: Truncated message.` when trying to perform `graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())` -- does this still work for you?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `tf.import_graph_def()` function doesn't have enough information to reconstruct the `tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES` collection (for that, you would need a [`MetaGraphDef`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/meta_graph)). However, if `output.pb` contains a "frozen" `GraphDef`, then all of the weights will be stored in [`tf.constant()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/constant) nodes in the graph. To extract them, you can do something like the following:

```
create_graph(GRAPH_DIR)

constant_values = {}

with tf.Session() as sess:
  constant_ops = [op for op in sess.graph.get_operations() if op.type == "Const"]
  for constant_op in constant_ops:
    constant_values[constant_op.name] = sess.run(constant_op.outputs[0])
```

Note that `constant_values` will probably contain more values than just the weights, so you may need to filter further by `op.name` or some other criterion.

Comment: I'm having trouble with the `create_graph()` above -- is there any reason that newer versions of TF (ie. 1.4+) would run into `DecodeError: Truncated message.`? Are there any existing TF functions that could replace the functionality of `create_graph()` above?