# Tensorflow: Importing pretrained model (mobilenet, .pb, .ckpt)

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have been investigating importing the checkpoint of a pretrained model in tensorflow.
The purpose of this is so that I can examine its structure, and use it for image
classification.

Specifically, the mobilenet model [found here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/slim).  I couldn't find any
reasonable way to import the model from the various **.ckpt.** files, and with
some forum sniffing I found a gist written by Github user StanislawAntol which
purported to convert said files into a frozen model, ProtoBuf (.pb) file. The
gist is [here](https://gist.github.com/StanislawAntol/656e3afe2d43864bb410d71e1c5789c1)

Running the script gives me a bunch of .pb files, which I would hope I could work
with.  Indeed, [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38947658/tensorflow-saving-into-loading-a-graph-from-a-file#) seemed to answer my prayers.

I have been trying variants of the following code, but no avail.  Any object that
was returned by `tf.import_graph_def` seemed to be of type None.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.platform import gfile

model_filename = LOCATION_OF_PB_FILE

with gfile.FastGFile(model_filename,'rb') as f:
graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
g_in = tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')

print(g_in)
```

Is there something I'm missing here?  Is the entire conversion to .pb erroneous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tf.import_graph_def` does not return the graph, it populates the "default graph" in the scope. See [documentation for `tf.import_graph_def`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/import_graph_def) for details on the return value.

In your case, you can inspect the graph using `tf.get_default_graph()`. For example:

```
with gfile.FastGFile(model_filename, 'rb') as f:
  graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
  graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')

g = tf.get_default_graph()
print(len(g.get_operations()))
```

See [documentation for `tf.Graph`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Graph) for more details on the notion of a "default graph" and scoping.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Marvelous, this has got me on the right track.  Thanks. Function on line 6 should be tf.get_default_graph()