# Convert model.ckpt to usable model

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm training an inception model from scratch using the scripts provided [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/inception/inception). 
The output of the training are these files:

```
checkpoint
events.out.tfevents.1499334145.fdbf-Dell
model.ckpt-5000.data-00000-of-00001
model.ckpt-5000.index
model.ckpt-5000.meta
...
model.ckpt-25000.data-00000-of-00001
model.ckpt-25000.index
model.ckpt-25000.meta
```

Does someone have a script to convert these files in something I can use to classify my images? I have already tried to modify the inception_train.py file to output the graph.pb, but nothing happens...

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: There are tons of questions about this on S.O., you didn't search too long...

Comment: There are tons of incomplete and partial answers everywhere. I was looking for a simple but complete script that could help me use these files. For instance, the "official" guide to train inception from scratch does explain how to train and how to evaluate the model, but does not explain how to use it to classify other images... why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to use your checkpoint directly is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43784657/7456923).

To create a .pb file, you'll have to freeze the graph, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34343517/7456923).

To create the initial .pb (or .pbtxt) file needed for freeze_graph, you can use [tf.train.write_graph()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/write_graph)

Comment: thanks. To freeze the graph it requires a graph.pbtxt file, which I cannot find anywhere... where should it be?